# Events on animations in expression blend 2 silverlight

Tags: silverlight, events, animation, expression-blend

I have just created a simple animation. Lets say that in one frame I have an image of the world. I would like to create an event when a certain country is chosen. How can I allow for the event to be triggered by clicking on one particular country in an image? e.g. just displaying the name of the country, etc

Thank you

Extra info: In other words I am trying to split my image into regions using Blend...Do I need to "Clip the image"? I clipped part of the image but dont know what to do now. can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want "hotspots" over the image that you can click on, you could simply draw some shapes over the areas and set their opacity to 0 then handle the mouse events on them(don't change visibility to collapsed, since that will mean they won't received any mouse events)

Comment: thanks for the reply.

When I create a shape it repeats itself for all the frames. How can I stop that from happening? Thanks